# lookup field control

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint-2007

I'm developing a windows application that updates item properties.

**what should i have to do if a document library have a lookup field or a people editor?

what is the control to use?**

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a combo box where the list contents are loaded dynamically when the user expands the list.

I hope, you are aware of the fact that, if you use SharePoint API (through microsoft.sharepoint.dll), you will only be able to run it on the server? If you need it to run on a remote machine, you have to consider using SharePoint Web Services.

Comment: I am using sharepoint web services, but my question is what control i have to add in my windows form for the lookup fields. Ex: for a single line of text field i will put a texbox control.